# Hide spelling and grammar error in Google Drive document

Tags: google-drive, google-docs

I am using Google Drive to create and edit a new document. How can I hide spelling and grammar errors in that document? I.e make the red lines below my words disappear

Comment: What is the use case? Are you spelling words incorrectly on purpose? Is it a product name that throws a red line?

Comment: I am writing the document in another language other than English, so red lines are everywhere

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Under "View" menu, un-select "Show spelling suggestions". I believe it's on a per user basis - effective to all documents you own.

Comment: Or change the language setting. File --> Language.

Comment: @Dave, that's another effective solution. Why don't you add it as an additional answer to the question so it is more visible to users? Comments are for more conversational purposes.

Comment: This answer is outdated.

Answer (score 2):

Or change the language setting. File -> Language

Answer (score 1):

**Updated answer**

`Tools -> Spelling -> Underline Errors` (Click to toggle)

`Tools -> Spelling -> Spell Check` (Click to toggle)